# Programmatically modifying styles in an external stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, content-security-policy

**Scenario:** You're publishing content to a content management system (think of some common blogging services). You're allowed to add your own stylesheet and scripts, but most of the page is *not* under your control and you *cannot* get it changed.

In your CSS you have a rule, say

```
ul { color: red; }
```

The service, however, has a "base" stylesheet installed, that says

```
ul.fancy { color: green !important; }
```

Now, if you want *all* your `ul`s to be red, you have to manually override with your own

```
ul.fancy { color: red !important; }
```

You can keep doing this as a last resort, but it gets a maintenance nightmare after a short while. It would be so much easier to just remove those rules! While you could copy their stylesheet to your personal storage, remove the annoying bits and rewrite the `style` tag to point to your new stylesheet (using JS), this will be problematic if they update their base stylesheet in the future, as changes will not be carried over.

Almost luckily we have the [CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) API that you could use to remove the offending rules. Except... the base stylesheet is loaded from a *different domain* than the rest of your site, so (both in Firefox and Chrome) you can't access the rules of that stylesheet with the API. (It works for embedded stylesheets, but not for those coming from different domains.)

**Question:** Is there any way to remove or modify CSS styles that are loaded from a different domain, using Javascript?